# How to add min/max (excluding outliers) values from linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, linear-regression

I have x/y data in .csv, calculated the linear regression between them, and added them to a plot.
I'd like to add two extra lines parallel to the trendline of the data, covering the min and max values (excluding outliers).

[image]

This is how it should look like.

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from numpy import polyfit
import pylab
from numpy import polyval

csv = 'Trendline.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, names=['x', 'y'])

x = df['x']
y = df['y']

fig = plt.figure(tight_layout=True)
plt.rc('grid', linestyle='--')

ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
ax1.scatter (x, y, marker = '+', color ='black')
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
ax1.grid (True)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)

z=np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p=np.poly1d(z)
pylab.plot(x, p(x), '-', color='grey')
print ('y=%.6fx+(%.6f)'%(z[0],z[1]))

slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = stats.linregress(x, y)
print('R2 value: ', rvalue**2)

fig.align_labels()
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

How could I adjust the code to include these extra lines and get their slope/intercept?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14fwYuIxX0VB33oQJlIsGK4bxNbxgkxFX/view?usp=sharing) is the .csv data.

Comment: You already have their slope (it's the same as the main regression line). Just solve it for the (x,y) of the min/max points you'd like the line the pass through.

Answer (score 0):

One way (among many others) to achieve your goal is first to identify the "bivariate outliers". To do this, apply the linear regression back to each observation of your sample obtaining the `y_prim` and then compute the residual as `y-y_prim`.

Then there is no strict definition of what constitutes an outlier, so several methods exist. One of the easiest is to use the [Tukey's fences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Tukey%27s_fences): every observation outside of the range `[Q1-1.5*IQR; Q3+1.5*IQR]` (where `Q1` is the first quartile, `Q3` is the third quartile and `IQR` is the inter-quartile range). Adding residual's Tukey's fences boundaries to the equation of linear regression gives you the equations of 2 additional lines covering the min and max values (excluding outliers) of your sample.

I amended your code with the above described procedure (note that I also cleaned the unnecessary imports, the reading of the csv file and removed the unnecessary call to `np.polyfit`):

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import pylab

csv = 'Trendline.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, decimal=",", sep=";", names=['x', 'y']).dropna()

x = df['x']
y = df['y']

# linear regression
slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = stats.linregress(x, y)
y_prime = slope*x+intercept
print ('y=%.6fx+(%.6f)'%(slope,intercept))
print('R2 value: ', rvalue**2)

# bivariate outliers identification
residual = y-y_prime
q1 = residual.quantile(0.25)
q3 = residual.quantile(0.75)
iqr = q3-q1
lower_boundary = q1-1.5*iqr
upper_boundary = q3+1.5*iqr

# plot
fig = plt.figure(tight_layout=True)
plt.rc('grid', linestyle='--')

ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
ax1.scatter (x, y, marker = '+', color ='black')
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
ax1.grid (True)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)

pylab.plot(x, y_prime, '-', color='grey')
pylab.plot(x, y_prime+lower_boundary, '-', color='grey')
pylab.plot(x, y_prime+upper_boundary, '-', color='grey')

fig.align_labels()
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```